# Perl elsif statement isn't working in apache2 script

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi

So I have to make a website that creates other websites using cgi scripts in apache.

My index.html has to use forms so that the user selects an option.

```
            <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <h1>Welcome to Magnum system check</h1>

            <form action="/cgi-bin/main.pl" method="POST" target="_blank">
              <input type="radio" name="option" value="processes" checked> View my processes<br>
              <input type="radio" name="option" value="calendar"> View the calendar<br>
              <input type="radio" name="option" value="location"> View my location coordinates<br>
              <input type="radio" name="option" value="users"> View all users connected on my system<br>
              <input type="radio" name="option" value="file"> Find a file or directory<br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            </body>
            </html>
```

This works fine. I tested the main.pl with this code to make sure that it was receiving different values.

```
            #!/usr/bin/perl
            use CGI qw(:standard);
            my $option = param('option');

            print header;
            print start_html("Main test");
            print h2("your option was $option");
            print end_html;
```

It printed the selected value in the newly created html. Now, since each option has to do something different, I decided to do an elsif for each option. (I tried using the given command but it never compiled).

So the problem with the following code is that it only works for the first option (processes). Any time I choose another option, it defaults to "Not Working".

```
            #!/usr/bin/perl
            use CGI qw(:standard);

            my $option = param('option');
            print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

            if($option eq "processes") {
                   print "Processes";
            } elsif(@option eq "calendar") {
                   print "Calendar";
            } elsif(@option eq "location") {
                    print "Location";
            } elsif(@option eq "users") {
                    print "Users";
            } elsif(@option eq "file") {
                    print "File";
            } else {
                   print "Not working";
            }
```

Any idea as to why it's not working? Or is there a better alternative to elsif?

Comment: Hint: `@option` is not the same thing as `$option`. 2nd hint: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: wow. I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: We all don't notice things sometimes. `use strict; use warnings;` will help you notice things.

Answer (score 1):

As @mob pointed out in comments, change all the `@option` to `$option`:

```
if($option eq "processes") {
       print "Processes";
} elsif($option eq "calendar") {
       print "Calendar";
} elsif($option eq "location") {
        print "Location";
} elsif($option eq "users") {
        print "Users";
} elsif($option eq "file") {
        print "File";
} else {
       print "Not working";
}
```

If you add this at the top of your script, Perl will give you warnings about undefined variables so that you can avoid such mistakes in the future:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```